# sort specific column in linux that have number, alphabet, and delimiter

Tags: linux, sort

I have been trying to sort specific column (column 2) with some data that have number,alphabetic,and delimiter in linux ( 9 million rows)

```
chr position p-value
10 chr10:6754:SG 0.2
1 chr1:68789:SG 0.6
16 chr16:68789:IG 0.88
9 chr9:68789:IG.0 0.4
1 chr1:8885436:SG:0 0.02
10 chr10:6788554:SG 0.01
```

my desired output file:

[image]

I run this code
sort -V -t: -k2,4n myfile  > sortedfile

but the output file does not sorted

Comment: [Please don't post images of text](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text).  Copy and paste the text itself **into your question** and format it as code by selecting it and pressing Ctrl-K or by using the editor's `{}` icon.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the `-t:` option.  That tells sort to ignore white space and to use only `:` characters as the field separator.

Try this:

```
$ sort -V -k2,2 input.txt 
1 chr1:68789:SG 0.6
1 chr1:8885436:SG:0 0.02
9 chr9:68789:IG.0 0.4
10 chr10:6754:SG 0.2
10 chr10:6788554:SG 0.01
16 chr16:68789:IG 0.88
chr position p-value
```

This is still using the -V option for a "version sort" but is sorting by ONLY the second field.

Better yet, to keep the header line as the first line:

```
$ head -n 1 input.txt ; tail -n +2 input.txt | sort -V -k2,2
chr position p-value
1 chr1:68789:SG 0.6
1 chr1:8885436:SG:0 0.02
9 chr9:68789:IG.0 0.4
10 chr10:6754:SG 0.2
10 chr10:6788554:SG 0.01
16 chr16:68789:IG 0.88
```

Comment: thanks Cas,i keep the header, but when i run this :  sort -V -k2,2 input.txt, it sort chr10 first not chr 1. how can i solve it?

Comment: i assume your real file is unsorted, or already has chr10 before chr1 - with `-k2,2` it sorts ONLY by the second field.  Try ` sort -V -k1,1 -k2,2` to sort it first by the first field, and then by the second field.

Comment: Many thanks Cas, it works. sort -V -k1,1 -k2,2n